# Multiplying a numeric string in java

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in programming and I've been doing the [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) programming problems to practice, I've been able to make my way so far, but this time I had to ask for help. Without spoilers, the problem I'm trying to solve consists of finding the sum of the digits of a very large number, so I can't hold it in an int or a double. So I made this method to multiply two strings containing a numeric value.

```
    private static String multiply(String a, String b) {

    // No, I'm not checking if the strings are numeric

    int subTotal = 1, extra = 0;

    String waitingString = "";
    StringBuilder number1 = new StringBuilder(a);
    StringBuilder number2 = new StringBuilder(b);
    List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    // The reason I reverse the numbers is the for() loops
    // I don't want to count down through the numbers, that
    // would just confuse me more.
    number1.reverse();
    number2.reverse();

    for (int i = 0; i < number1.length(); i++) {

        waitingString = "";
        subTotal = Character.getNumericValue(number1.charAt(i));

        for (int j = 0; j < number2.length(); j++) {

            subTotal *= Character.getNumericValue(number2.charAt(j));
            subTotal += extra;

            char[] temp = String.valueOf(subTotal).toCharArray();
            waitingString = temp[temp.length - 1] + waitingString;

            if (subTotal >= 10 || ((j == number2.length() - 1) && (String.valueOf(subTotal).length() > 1))) {

                extra = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(subTotal).substring(0, temp.length - 1));

            } else {

                extra = 0;

            }

            subTotal = Character.getNumericValue(number1.charAt(i));

        }

        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            waitingString += "0";
        }

        waitingString = extra + "" + waitingString;

        numbers.add(waitingString);

    }

    // sumAll() is not the problem just in case you were wondering.
    // Because as you've read the code, I'm passing a List<String>
    // to it and as I was trying to find the error I printed the list
    // before everything to check the values and the error was already
    // there, 3 of the values are wrong.
    return sumAll(numbers);
}
```

When testing I'm multiplying this number by itself: 1125899906842624. The result should be 1267650600228229401496703205376. But I'm getting 1267650600228229401607703205376. That's a difference of 111000000000. I've been trying to find the error for 2 days and i just can't.
I'm not looking for alternative or better ways to do this, I just can't find the error in my code that adds more than it should.
If you need to see the rest of the code I can provide it and please don't mind spelling/grammar errors, english is not my native language.

Comment: Might I introduce you to the [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class? :)

Comment: I'm gonna try it but I still wanna know why my code isn't working properly :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without trying to run this or look at it under a debugger: it looks like you're setting up an `extra` variable which is a carry, i.e. the value which should get added to the next product as you move to the left (in your original numbers, not the reversed ones).  One problem I can see is that if the *last* product in your inner loop produces something greater than or equal to 10, you compute `extra`; but then when you go the next *outer* loop, `extra` still has that value and gets added to `subTotal` when it shouldn't be.  Try adding the statement `extra = 0;` at the beginning of your outer loop, and before the inner loop starts.  That may fix the problem.

P.S. You're making a lot of extra work for yourself by representing the `subTotal` as a string and working with it.  While I understand why you'd want to use strings for the two multiplicands and the product, `subTotal` is the product of two single digits with a carry added, and it can never be greater than 89.  So you should never have to convert it to a string and work with the string.  Thus, instead of

```
char[] temp = String.valueOf(subTotal).toCharArray();
waitingString = temp[temp.length - 1] + waitingString;
```

you could say

```
waitingString = String.valueOf(subTotal % 10) + waitingString;
```

or something similar (`subTotal % 10` gives the remainder when subTotal is divided by 10, and is therefore the last digit of `subTotal`); and instead of the complex code to compute `extra`, just say

```
extra = subTotal / 10;
```

which divides by 10 and throws away the remainder.  You shouldn't be computing `String.valueOf(subTotal)` at all.

PPS. Don't worry about the answers that tell you to use `BigInteger`.  If you were doing a real programming project, that's what you'd use.  But for someone learning how to program, I think that writing a program to compute the product of two numbers, the long way, is a good learning tool.

Answer (score 1):

As someone commented, this would probably be a job for the `BigInteger` class. Just say

```
BigInteger intA = new BigInteger(a)
BigInteger intB = new BigInteger(b)
```

and then call

```
intA.multiply(intB)
```

and that will get you a `BigInteger` containing the result.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) like this

```
private static String multiply(String a, String b) {
  if (a == null || b == null) {
    if (b != null) return b;
    return a;
  }
  BigInteger v = new BigInteger(a, 10);
  if (v != null) {
    BigInteger t = new BigInteger(b, 10);
    if (t != null) {
      BigInteger r = v.multiply(t);
      return r.toString();
    }
  }

  return "";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String result = multiply("1125899906842624", "1125899906842624");
  String good = "1267650600228229401496703205376";
  System.out.println(result.equals(good));
}
```

Which prints `true` when I run it.